# How do I filter all incoming requests and not just ones mapped to servlets?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, servlet-filters

I am toying around with embedded Jetty and I am wondering why my filter *only* intercepts `/hi` and not any other incoming request. Here is my example case:

Without Filter:

```
localhost:8080/hi
=> "Hello"
localhost:8080/foo
=> 404
```

With Filter:

```
localhost:8080/hi
=> "Hello from filter"
localhost:8080/foo
=> 404
```

I would expect the last 404 to return "Hello from filter". What am I missing?

```
Server server=new Server(8080);

ServletContextHandler context=
    new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

context.setContextPath("/");
context.addFilter(DispatchFilter.class,"/*",1);
context.addServlet(HelloServlet.class,"/hi");

server.setHandler(context);
server.start();
server.join();
```

To further clarify, my example is just a simplified representation of what I want to do. My intention is to have the `DispatchFilter` intercept every request. If a certain criteria is not met, then it should move on, otherwise return something derived from the request path.

Comment: A 404 error is often returned when pages have been moved or deleted.

Comment: @Suresh: I know what a 404 error means. That's not applicable to my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [javax.servlet.Filter.doFilter()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html#doFilter)

> The doFilter method of the Filter is
>   called by the container each time a
>   request/response pair is passed
>   through the chain due to a client
>   request for a resource at the end of
>   the chain.

The key part here is the bit about the "end of the chain". Since /foo doesn't match an actual resource, the filters are not executed.

You can work around this by adding a default servlet:

```
context.addServlet(org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet, "/");
```

Now all your requests have a valid endpoint and your filter will be executed.

Comment: Interesting. Then I am curious how frameworks like Struts2 do it. http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1.1/docs/webxml.html

Comment: I believe this works because app servers generally have a default servlet mapping for serving up static content.

Comment: Ah, yes. Jetty provides a `DefaultServlet` class. Once adding that everything works as expected. Thanks!